# How do I make Apex text field required value dynamically

Tags: javascript, oracle, oracle-apex

I have JS line

*document.getElementById(element).required=true;*

How do I make it work in Oracle APEX?

I have a form with select list that has values Yes/No.
If a value is "Yes", 2 more text fields appear. I have done it by making dynamic action (when item is changed and gets specific value) but there was no option to set required values, so I tried to "Execute JS code".

But JS line above didn't work.

Comment: Which version of Apex are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must add two conditionals validations for those text fields.

1. Set field template as required, but leave it "Is Required" as "No".
   [image]
2. Add a validation for each field and make it "Conditional" setting it condition type to "Value of Item / Column in Expression 1 = Expression 2". On "Expression 1" set your select Name and "Expression 2" to desired value. 
   **Add Condition**
   [image]
   **Validation Level**
   [image]
   **Validation Type**
   [image]
   **Condition**
   [image]

Answer (score -1):

When you make an item required it is **always** required when you submit the form. You'll have to resort to page validations to check if it has a value in specific cases.